# Batch/CMD stops after OpenVPN command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dns, openvpn, connection-leaks

I'm trying to create an auto connect and disconnect file with the OpenVPN and in addition to that, set my WiFi adapters DNS to 0.0.0.0 (becuase of DNS leaks) and back to normal.

Here's my current code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=openvpn-gui.exe
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto NOT
goto RUNS

:NOT
taskkill /im openvpn-gui.exe /f
taskkill /im openvpn.exe /f
netsh interface IPv4 set dnsserver "WiFi" dhcp
ipconfig /flushdns
exit

:RUNS
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin"
openvpn-gui.exe --connect "vpn-connection-file.ovpn" 

netsh interface IPv4 set dnsserver "WiFi" static 0.0.0.0 both
ipconfig /flushdns
exit
```

The first lines of my codes checks if openVPN is running, if it does, go to RUN, else to NOT.

NOT is ending OpenVPN and sets DNS back to normal.

RUN is opening OpenVPN and esatblishes a connection to my config file.

However, after this line:

```
openvpn-gui.exe --connect "vpn-connection-file.ovpn"
```

CMD won't continue with the rest of the codes. It just stops, and the white space bar is blinking. (Not possible to enter any keys or whatever.)
Checking if the rest of the codes have been executed is negative.

Anybody know whats going on here?

Comment: Did you try `Start openvpn...`?

Comment: What happens if you just open a command prompt and run the openvpn.exe command as it is in your batch file? What is the behavior then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD waits for `openvpn-gui.exe` to end. Try it with `start`

```
start openvpn-gui.exe --connect "vpn-connection-file.ovpn"
```

Comment: That's why the "Answer the question" fields are for ;-)

Comment: @Tanckom, the comment section is also useful for "This was the answer, thank you Compo, if you add it as an answer, I will accept it".